# Estimating a expectation value of a function of a random variable and a non-probability variable using Monte Carlo simulation.

Tags: monte-carlo, simulation

I have a function $g(x,Z)$, where $Z$ has a normal distribution, and $x$ is NOT a random variable (I have a range of pre-specified values to evaluate), and I want to generate a plot of the expectation value $E[g(x)]$, or $E[g](x)$.

In order to use Monte Carlo simulation to generate this plot with $n=1000$ draws of $Z$, must I resample $Z$ anew for every value of $x$ that I plan to evaluate? Or can I rely on the same $n=1000$ sample of $Z$ values for every value of $x$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can consider that $g(x,Z)$ is a set of trajectories, where each trajectory is the curve associated with the function $g(\cdot, z)$, where $z$ is a sample of $Z$. The expected value $E[g](x)$ is just the mean of all these trajectories when evaluated on $x$. Using this point of view, we can say that we have $n = 1000$ trajectories, and we want to take the average on our values of $x$. In this scenario, we can use the same $n$ simulations to compute the average for each $x$. This has the advantage of being really efficient compared to take $n=1000$ simulations for each value of $x$. However, if our simulations are somehow skewed, **all** our estimates will be skewed as well, which could be a reason not to use the same simulations for each $x$.

At the end of the day, I think that as long as you have enough simulations, there's no problem in reusing them (for this particular case).

Comment: Thank you @rarwoan. I agree that the skewness (hopefully negligibly small) will apply at every value of x. As a non-mathematician, I am wondering if this is a statistically valid approach for estimating E[g](x)? In other words, will this be torn apart in peer review?

And is it correct to call this approach a Monte Carlo simulation?

Comment: The "Monte Carlo simulation" name applies mostly when you are trying to approximate an integral using samples from a random variable, as $E[g](x) = \int g(x,z) dz$ (over the support of $Z$) you are actually doing it. If you want to study the values $E[g](x) $ separately for each $x$ it's correct to take different samples of $Z$. However, if you want to study the properties of the trajectories associated with $g(x,Z)$, it's more appealing to share simulations, both seem statistically coherent to me (depending on what you want to study).